# Cannot convert date string to datevalue in Excel

Tags: excel

I have some dates in a string in a column. 
Because the format seems to be M/DD/YYYY I sometimes get a VALUE error when using DATEVALUE.
How can I convert a column to make sure all dates are correct.
For example, the following 2 cells

```
9/29/2006 12:49:58.956 AM DATEVALUE gives an error
9/12/2008 5:36:59.356 PM DATEVALUE converts to 39791
```

Comment: If you Just want the date then use `=INT(A1)` it will cut the time and return the date.  Then you could either wrap that in `TEXT(...,"m/dd/yyyy")` or just change the format of the cell to short date.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the range (just one colunm) with the dates... Go to:

(in Excel 2010)

```
Data >>> Text to Columns
```

[image]
Inside the dialog box select:

```
Delimited >>> Next
```

[image]

Just select `Tab` checkbox.

[image]

And heres is the magic! 
You need to define the arrangement for your dates...

[image]

In the `Date` field: 
Choose the what you need (as you say in your question is `M/D/Y`)

`Destination` field: 
Make sure that is the same of the data you want to format.

And finish.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is probably that the data is getting interpreted as a general field, and shows up as, say 49:59.0 - which isn't text, which is what Datevalue() expects as input; for both inputs, Datevalue(CellID) words if you prepend the text with a ' - which ensures it is treated as text.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your system settings use `dd/mm/yyyy` for short date format. and `datevalue` function uses this settings, so its try to read the day from the first part of the string and the month from the second part. as in your example `9/29/2006 12:49:58.956 AM` there is no month with 29 then it gives error, and in the second example it gives 39791 = 9 december 2008 and NOT 12 september 2008.

If you change the short date format in your system settings to `mm/dd/yyyy`then `datevalue` function will work correctly, but this not acceptable, so we need to replace month with day and day with month to get correct date.

I don't know if we can do this with Excel formula but we can do that simply with VBA.
So try this code:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim d1 As Variant, d2 As Variant, td As Date
  Dim Rng As Range, CL As Range

  Set Rng = Range("A1:A2") ' change this to your range

  For Each CL In Rng

     d1 = Split(CL.Value, " ")
     d2 = Split(d1(0), "/")
     td = DateSerial(d2(2), d2(0), d2(1))
     CL.Offset(0, 1) = td
     CL.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy" ' change the Date format as you need
     'CL.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

  Next
End Sub
```